# Is a "Permanent Sticking Charm" actually permanent?

Tags: harry-potter

The only instances I can remember of permanent sticking charms is with Mrs. Black's portrait, the Black family tree tapestry, and the photo of Sirius and his friends in his bedroom. The removal of all of these items is only attempted by people who did not cast the charm.

Is there any evidence that the person who cast the charm is able to reverse it? Is it permanent in that until the person reverses the charm it cannot be unstuck or is it permanent for everyone once it's cast, including the caster?

Comment: There's also the portrait in the Prime Minister's office, although I don't think it is explicitly stated that a permanent sticking charm was used.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Permanent_Sticking_Charm

Comment: I thought that when they were removing some of the things from the black house some of them had permanent sticking charms which were removed others were harder to remove or something? I could be wrong probably worth a look up

Comment: @Simon No, they couldn't get anything down with a permanent sticking charm; that's why they still had Sirius's mum up there.

Answer (score 1):

I could find two "evidences" for it. And I'll admit none of those are especially strong but I'm throwing them anyway. The wiki points out that there is no specialized counter spell, but that doesn't mean the charm can't be broken by force or by "wrestling" it.

First one is that the Weasley twins joked about sticking Ron's badge to his forehead. While their sense of humor can be somewhat extreme at times, I find it funny that'd they'd joke about a truly permanent charm. But as the wiki points out, it's never said if the spell can be circumvented by simply removing part of the surface it's cast on (which would be ron's skin).

On a more general level, I don't remember any spell/enchantment that can't be reversed, cancelled or at least affected by the caster. As such, my guess is that it an be reversed.

*Note : the following paragraph is mostly guesswork*

Now we have examples of portraits like Sirius' mother resisting many wizards (Sirius amongst them) for a long time. And Sirius' pictures resisting his mother for a long time too. What that tells me is that even if Sirius' mother is the most powerful wizard of the two, she couldn't break it and Dumbledore probably tried to break it. None of those worked. What that tells me is that it's *probably* removable, but akin to an encrypted communication. The remover need to have precise knowledge of the way the spell was cast (or have a *mental fingerprint* of the caster) to realistically break it.